# Choosing the right query in SQLite in Dao

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, mvvm, android-sqlite

I am trying to extract data from my database from the "Hyperglycemia" column. In this comparison there are only two yes or no kobination. I would like to ask a question in order to get the calculated sum of all the words YES. Somehow it doesn't work out for me. Someone knows and would be willing to help. Thank you very much.

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT sum(Hiperglikemi) FROM Pomiar WHERE Hiperglikemia LIKE 'YES'")
    fun hiperglikemiaYES():LiveData<String>
```

ROOM

```
@Entity
data class Pomiar(
    @ColumnInfo(name="Stezenie")
    val Stezenie: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="Data")
    val Data: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="Zegar")
    val Zegar: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="Posilek")
    val Posilek: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="Samopoczucie")
    val Samopoczucie: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="Stres")
    val Stres: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="Hiperglikemia")
    val Hiperglikemia: String?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Pomiar WHERE Hiperglikemia = 'YES'
```

or:

```
SELECT sum(Hiperglikemia = 'YES') FROM Pomiar
```

Also check the spelling of the column: `Hyperglycemia` or `Hiperglikemia`?